# Jackson 2.8.9 @JsonPropertyOrder does not arrange field that is generated by @JsonTypeInfo when serializing XML

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to serialize and deserialize XML in the following format:

```
<home>
    <handle>300023</handle>
    <command>login</command>
    <content>
        <user_id>300023</user_id>
        <result>0</result>
    </content>
</home>
```

and try to map it to the following classes:

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "home")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"handle", "command", "content"})
public class Home {

    private long handle;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
      include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
      visible = true,
      property = "command")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LoginContent.class, name = "login")
    })
    private BaseContent content;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "user_id",
    "result"})
public class LoginContent implements BaseContent{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user_id")
    private long userId;
    private int result;
}
```

The problem occurs when I serialize with

```
Home home = new Home();
home.setHandle(300023);
LoginContent content = new LoginContent();
content.setUserId(300023);
content.setResult(0);
home.setContent(content);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
String xmlString = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(home);
```

xmlString return as xml with correct fields but incorrect order as @JsonPropertyOrder

```
<home>
    <handle>300023</handle>
    <content>
        <user_id>300023</user_id>
        <result>0</result>
    </content>
    <command>login</command>
</home>
```

The implementing class type of `content` is based on the value of `<command>`, which is in the same level as `<content>`, hence the usage of `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY`. 
Since the deserialization is working as expected, I excluded other implementing classes of BaseContent.
Now I am looking for a way I can make `@JsonPropertyOrder` effective with fields that is generated by `@JsonTypeInfo`. I have tried to add `command` field in `Home.class`, but it will result in a duplicated tag in the xml.

What would be the correct way to achieve this? Or is there other better way of doing this (serialize and deserialize mentioned xml with `content` varies based on `command` value with specific order)?

Thanks in advance.